# How can I implement Cleanup in TestComplete

Tags: automated-tests, testcomplete

I'm developing a test automation framework in TestComplete. I am looking for a way to call my cleanup method after finishing all the test items in all the projects in a Project Suite.
Somebody suggested using OnStopTest event handler, but it's useless in my case because it will be called everytime an test item stops and I want the method to be called only at the end after running all the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a final test item at the end of test flow and perform any finalization actions in it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking about the same workaround and for this I have to add a project for cleanup to my project suite (I have work items in different projects in a project suite that contain work items and they will run in a secuence specified in project suite). by the way there is one situation which left unhandled by this workaround: what if test execution stops in the middle of work manualy or by other reasons? that way It won't reach to execution of the last work item and test run finishes without a proper cleanup.

Comment: You can use the OnStopTest event handler in order to perform some cleanup code when a test execution is finished. However please note that this event is fired when execution of every test item is finished.